# Document Viewer for Node JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pdf, tiff

I am trying to find a library that can help me implement a document viewer for Node Js as my backend and Angular Js for my frontend web application. Basically this document viewer should be able to support pdf and tiff file formats. It should also help me edit the documents like rotate a page, move a page or delete the page and then submit the edited document. Most of the document viewer libraries i found were for asp.net and paid. Most of the libraries I found for Node JS were just for viewing purposes but not editing them. I would welcome any suggestions or help that can put me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PDF editing: https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS

For Tiff editing: http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/

For PDF rendering on the client: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

For Tiff rendering: convert it into jpg/png